# Send email with Express and EmailJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I try to send email with EmailJS module for Express but it works only in local, it doesn't work in remote (AppFog)... I don't understand the problem...

```
var email   = require("emailjs");

var server = email.server.connect({
    user: "******",
    password: "******",
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    ssl: true
});

var send = function(message, from, subject) {
    server.send({
        text:    message,
        from:    from,
        to:      "******** <*********>",
        subject: subject
    });
}

exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('contact', {
        emailSuccess: false,
        title: "my title"
    });
}

exports.send = function(req, res) {
    send(req.body.message, req.body.from, req.body.subject);
    res.render('contact', {
        emailSuccess: true,
        title: "my title"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppFog blocks SMTP outgoing requests to prevent spam.

You'll need to use a service such as Sendgrid, Amazon SES, Postmark, etc...

Comment: Ok and what is the free best one?

Comment: Can't really vouch for which is best, and only few have free dev accounts.  I've used Sendgrid (but I'm not sure they have a free plan directly, but they offer one via heroku).  Amazon SES has a free plan if you send from an EC2 instance (which could work if you use an EC2 hosted instance on AppFog).